# Connection dropping in Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04

Our Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS keeps dropping connection sporadically such as after a few hours and sometimes after a few days, even weeks but last night it happened within 3 hours, I am unable to SSH in remotely when it happens so when I physically login to the server I can't get a connection so I am forced to reboot and then I am back online.

It has 2 networks cards in it so I configured the second one and changed to that one to see if it's possibly a faulty card and it is still happening.

I've already checked the obvious log files such as messages, dmesg, etc.

Does anyone know what it could possibly that's causing this or what I could do to pinpoint the issue?

Comment: Logs? syslog, dmesg etc.

Comment: checked those. nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out both cards were duds.